# Lagrangian maximisation of a convex function

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra

Having two real matrices $X_1$ and $X_2$ of size $(n,p_1)$ and $(n,p_2)$ respectively. I am trying to find the optimal vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $|u^TX_1^TX_2v|$ is maximum, with the constrains $||v||_2=1$ and $||u||_2=1$.

Is the Lagrangian of these equations sufficient to solve this problem. Knowing that we are in the maximisation of a convex function.

Comment: Have you written out the Lagrangian and tried it? What point are you stuck on?

Comment: Why do you formulate your question in this overly complicated way?  You have *one* matrix $A=X_1^\prime X_2$ of dimensions $p_1\times p_2.$ The solution is revealed by the SVD of $A.$